android compose materialTheme.colorScheme.background does not apply in card containerColor
While the background color is applied to other components including the border, only the container color does not have the background color applied.
Exactly, the background color seems to be applied, but it is not the desired color.

import androidx.compose.material3.Card
import androidx.compose.material3.CardDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Text

val md_theme_light_background = Color(0xFFFFFBFF) // The background color is almost white.

Card(
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
            containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            disabledContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            disabledContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
        ),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 10.dp),
        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
    ) {
            Text(text = "text text text")
    }

screenShot 1
Card(
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
            containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background, // not desired color
            contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            disabledContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            disabledContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
        ),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 10.dp),
        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) // desired color
    ) {
            Text(text = "text text text")
    }

screenShot 2

Of course, using Color.White or Color(0xFFFFFBFF) solves the problem.
But I wonder what causes it.
Is the problem occurring within CardDefaults.cardColors?

See my answer on a similar question earlier:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78386407/9015942
Since you are specifying a high elevation of 10dp, tonal elevation is applied at a high rate. Either set the elevation to 0; or if you need a shadow, use Surface instead, which allows specifying tonal and shadow elevation separately

Thank you. After delete elevation, it works !
